# SSI element stretches outside of page width

Tags: html, css, menu, width, ssi

the html menu that i have inserted into the page through SSI is stretching to the left beyond the hard coded width of the page and i can't figure out why...

if you look at my code, the #menu id is the problem as it is floating properly (float:right;) but the width it seem is being overridden by something....and i can't find out what is overriding it.....i've checked all the properties that would affect #menu but nothing has an effect on it...

here is the webpage where it is clear: http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/homepage.html

here is the css for the homepage where the menu is insert:

```
body{
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 10px;
}

html{
height: 100%;
}   

#wrapper{
width: 900px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

#header{
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

here is the corresponding html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<!--#include virtual="/menus/menu.html" -->
</div>
```

here is the css for the menu page:

```
#menu-wrapper{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 140px;
}

#logo{
background:url('http://www.unifiedforuganda.com/resources/u4ulogo.jpg') no-repeat;
height: 108px;
width: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 3px;
background-position: 0 0;
float: left;
}

#logo span{
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
    background:url('file:///Volumes/Despotos/Users/nojohnny101/Documents/Dropbox/Unified%20for%20UNIFAT/website/resources/u4ulogo.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: -200px 0;
}

#logo:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
}


 .social{
position: relative;
margin: 50px 0 0 0;
width: 136px;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
}
#menu{
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
list-style: none;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 4px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
float: right;
}
```

then here is the html for the menu page:

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
<div class="menu-header">
    <a href="http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/homepage.html" id="logo" class="imglink"><span></span></a>
</div>
<div class="social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/UnifiedforUNIFAT" id="facebook" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/unified4unifat" id="twitter" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="http://unifiedforunifat.wordpress.com/" id="wordpress" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="https://vimeo.com/u4u" id="vimeo" target="_blank"><span></span></a>

</div>
<div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">US MOVEMENT</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/ugandaprograms.html">UGANDA PROGRAMS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: Your include file should not be a complete HTML file. SSI doesn't work like that; the result is supposed to be a proper HTML document, with one DOCTYPE declaration, one `<html>` element and so on. Frankly I'm surprised it comes out as nice as it does.

Comment: @MrLister oh i never knew that.....but the <body></body> tags should be there correct? what about styling? i have to have some referenced css in the <head></head> because that is what styles the thing right? can you be more specific about what exactly doesn't need to be there?

Comment: A HTML document (that is, the output of the SSI file, as your browser gets to see it) must follow the basic HTML rules. One DOCTYPE declaration, followed by one `<html>` element that contains one `<head>` and one `<body>` element, in that order. So if you include something inside the body, that what you include can not contain `<html>` and `<body>` elements of its own. What you posted there, as "the html for the menu page", _that_ should be the contents of the included file, nothing else.

Comment: Also, IDs must be unique; you can't have two divs with id="wrapper". But we'll get to that later.

Comment: gotcha....makes total sense.....i'm just learning this stuff (started about 4 days ago) and so code efficiency is not something that is in the front of my mind although i am trying, never would have though of that....
ok so i linked the menu.css from the homepage.html and then removed all the unnecessary html from the menu.html page and then also changed so there are no id conflicts....i've updated the question code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the answer...what i ended up doing was put the overflow: hidden; property on the #menu-wrapper id....i don't know if i totally understand why this helped to hide the extra width to the left of the page even though a hard width was specified (900px) and the border is actually applied to the #menu id not the #menu-wrapper id.....

but problem....thanks @MrLister